# Dynamo db fails partially to update record

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have an app which updates the entries in dynamo-DB which is nothing but the updating UTC timestamp of the current time.
I have a task where I am trying to update all 94000 records, using new UTC timestamp.
My Current dynamo-DB configuration has a capacity of 80 units of reading & writing.
After finishing this task, I checked & it updated the records up to 50% but not all.
All update operations are performed on existing indexed with 80 Unit Read/Right capacity.

What if I am exceeding the write capacity? will it still update the records with some delay? or it will just give up on halfway?

```
 result = cls.db_table.scan(req_id__eq=str(req.id))
        for req in result:
             req['timestamp'] = time() * 1000
            if not req.partial_save():
                LOGGER.error('Unable to update req {}'.format(req.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

**What if I am exceeding the write capacity?**

On exceeding the write capacity units, DynamoDB will throw ProvisionedThroughputExceededException.

**will it still update the records with some delay? or it will just give up on halfway?**

It will Raise exception once the write capacity units are exceeded. However DynamoDB can handle some burst writes but not for a long duration.

Comment: am using boto library on python, am not getting ProvisionedThroughputExceededException at all but I did get a dynamodb alarm in AWS console, saying read/ write capacity exceeded.

        for lead in result:
            lead['timestamp'] = time() * 1000
            if not lead.partial_save():
                LOGGER.error('Unable to update lead {}'.format(lead.items()))
i do not get any log either.

Comment: @ROHIT What is the response you are getting?

Comment: lead.partial_save() always returns true so from my code side I cannot tell if it's updated / not

Comment: @ROHIT could you please post your code snippet that's doing this?

Comment: Updated my question with a snippet.